# Splitting a string based on the character after the delimeter - python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to split a string based on the character after the character that it is being split by. For example,

```
k="I would like to eat you"
specialsplit(k,' ')
```

would return

```
['I ', 'ould ', 'ike ', 'o ', 'at ', 'ou']
```

and

```
k="I would like to eat you"
specialsplit(k,'e')
```

would return

```
['I would like', 'to e', 't you']
```

The character that it is being split by doesn't go away like the normal split works, but the character after it does. I've tried

```
def specialsplit(k,d):
    return [e[1:]+d if c!=0 or c==(len(k)-1) else e[:-1] if c==len(k)-1 else e+d for c,e in enumerate(k.split(d))]
```

but it always adds the character being split by to the last element, so in the second example, it returned `['I would like', 'to e', 't youe']` instead of `['I would like', 'to e', 't you']`. How could I fix this code, or how else could I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
def specialsplit(_input, _char):
  return re.split(f'(?<={_char})[\w\W]', _input)

print([specialsplit("I would like to eat you", i) for i in [' ', 'e']])
```

Output:

```
[['I ', 'ould ', 'ike ', 'o ', 'at ', 'ou'], ['I would like', 'to e', 't you']]
```